# How to Convert Datareader Result of DbType.Time to Timespan Object?

Tags: c#, time, data-access, timespan, daab

I am reading a result from a MS SQL 2008 Database with a column type of dbtype.time from a datareader, using c# with DAAB 4.0 framework.

My problem is the MSDN docs say dbtype.time should map to a timespan but the only close constructor for timespan I see accepts a long, and the result returned from the datareader cannot be cast to a long, or directly to a timespan.

I found this [Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/usisvde/archive/2007/11/14/time-for-ado-net.aspx) whichs shows datareader.getTimeSpan() method, but the datareader in daab 4.0 does not seem to have this method.

So how do I convert the result from the datareader to a timespan object ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GetTimeSpan` is a method of `OleDbDataReader` and `SqlDataReader` (but not of the more generic IDataReader interface which DAAB's `ExecuteReader` returns).  I'm assuming that the `IDataReader` instance which DAAB has returned to you is actually an instance of `SqlDataReader`.  This allows you to access the `GetTimeSpan` method by casting the `IDataReader` instance appropiately:

```
using (IDataReader dr = db.ExecuteReader(command))
{
    /* ... your code ... */
    if (dr is SqlDataReader)
    {
        TimeSpan myTimeSpan = ((SqlDataReader)dr).GetTimeSpan(columnIndex)
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("The DataReader is not a SqlDataReader")
    }
    /* ... your code ... */
}
```

Edit:  If the `IDataReader` instance is not a `SqlDataReader` then you might be missing the `provider` attribute of your connection string defined in your app.config (or web.config).

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried a direct cast like this?

```
TimeSpan span = (TimeSpan)reader["timeField"];
```

I just tested this quickly on my machine and works fine when "timeField" is a Time datatype in the database (SQL).

Comment: Both yours and Ken's solutions are good. However, if the value is null, Ken's solution's exception message is more descriptive. `SqlNullValueException - Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values` VS `InvalidCastException - Specified cast is not valid`.

Comment: To answer BishopBarber comment if the column can be nullable you should convert it to TimeSpan? nullable type and check for null. `TimeSpan? span = reader["tsfield"] == DBNull.Value ? (TimeSpan?) null : (TimeSpan?) reader["tsfield"]`

Comment: I found this solution better because I often don't access my data reader by index. I do however have an intermediate method that checks for null.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take:

```
using (IDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(command))
{
    var timeSpan = reader.GetDateTime(index).TimeOfDay;
}
```

Cleaner, perhaps!

Comment: The database layer throws an `InvalidCastException` for me when it returns a `TIME` type but I try to read with `GetDateTime()`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the .NET type of the column value?  If it is a DateTime then you can pass the value of its Ticks property (long) to the TimeSpan constructor.  E.g.

```
var span = new TimeSpan(colValue.Ticks);
```